# how to validate my json

Tags: json, google-chrome, console, lint

I know about `jsonlint` but it expects keys to be strings. I want to validate a json just like on command line. I tried on chrome's console window but I can't know where is the error in parsing. It just says `Unexpected token :` and doesn't tell me where.

Comment: jsonlint follows the json spec... keys must be strings. unless it's an array, in which case keys are ommitted.

Comment: Valid JSON does indeed require keys to be strings. (As opposed to JavaScript objects, which doesn't require the quotes). How come your JSON is malformed in this way?

Comment: ok then I guess I mean javascript objects. How do I validate them?